# Stored procedure or LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a webshop created in ASP.net MVC 2 with a database SQL server.

If I need to make filtration for instance specfic products from the stock in database via webshop.

Which options should I choose and why?

1. Make the filtration via stored procedure?
2. Using LINQ as a C-sharp coding?
3. Another solution?

Comment: Is this a one-off filter for a report, or a very common filter that will be executed on every web request, or something in between? As always there's a development-time vs run-time trade-off.

Comment: Stored Procedures in Manage Code, would be a third solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxsa8hkf(v=vs.80).aspx. After reviewing the third solution everything Rup said about the trade-off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would only use stored procedure if you really want to optimize your sql. Otherwise if you want to keep it flexible and make it possible to plugin filters easily I would recommend a type pipes and filters pattern. It would work like this:

```
public class ProductRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Prodcut> GetAll() 
    {
        return yourContext.Products;
    }
}

public static class ProductFilters
{
    public static IQueryable<Product> ByCategory(this IQueryable<Product> query, string category)
    {
        return query.Where(p => p.Category == category);
    }
}
```

The name `ProductRepository` is probably wrong in this case since it is not truly a repository, more some kind of "bridge". But this pattern allow you to easily add additional filters like extension methods. It is important that you return `IQueryable` from the extension methods and your "repository", this make the query to be evaluated only once and you can chain your filters.

Comment: Tack så mycket för din rådgivning! :)

Comment: How do I know you're swedish because of one sentence... so here it is in English (and that how it should be on this forum so every one can read). First, you're welcome... and second, a tip for you is to start accepting answers to your question otherwise people will stop answering you. 11 % acceptance ration is not much.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following in similar cases:

1. [Devart LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/)
2. Creating stored procedures (for SQL optimizing)
3. Include these procedures to the model and work with [complex types](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/ValueType.html)