# Should I use a stored procedure or linq to extract adhoc data

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

(Note, I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583936/stored-procedure-or-linq) but I believe this question isn't opinion based)

Now I can either

**OPTION 1 : use a stored procedure**

I can write a stored procedure in SQL Server which takes the tank's product id and returns the people who have bought it. If for someone reason some people who should have been picked up don't get picked by the stored procedure (perhaps a logical bug in the procedure, or perhaps I forget to add a condition), I can easily test the stored procedure against the database

But that would be a long stored procedure :(

**OPTION 2 : use Linq**

Alternatively, if I do it all in Linq and write my unit /integration tests and later discover that for some reason some people aren't getting picked up, it will be very difficult to test why, because the tests will be running against my mock data, not the actual database server.

Also, code will have to be recompiled if there is a bug found in linq query.

What should be the preferred way here given that it makes it easier to test the logic? I personally like linq way better but I am worried about finding a small bug later in the selection logic and causing debugging headaches.

Thank you

Comment: Are you entitled to make a copy of the actual production data? Or is that not possible for any of a number of perfectly legitimate reasons? If it were, you could simply code your work against that data.

If it isn't possible, I am going to assume you've been contracted to create this application you're working on. In that case, your client (the party who contracted you) could simply provide you with real-world mock data that incorporates every possible scenario. So you can test either approach against every possible contigency.

Comment: thanks, no I won't have access to live data but I will have a copy of live data ( anonymised by a tool ) .

Comment: Well, given the fact it's only been anonymised, I would venture to guess that the relevant data you're interested to test either approach against is still present in the data you have received.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based regardless, because I was just considering posting an answer *exactly opposite* to the one that says "I prefer to use LINQ". Both approaches have their pros and cons, it's still too hard to answer the question as given here in an objective manner. Both LINQ and stored procedures can be *made* testable to any desired degree, and the way I see it, which is "easier" critically depends on what you're used to and how much experience you have with either.

Comment: I reckon you need to look into FULL TEXT SEARCH (BTW A TANK with Warhead, not a good example in anyone's book - who are your customers?? kim il jong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a preference, but I prefer to use linq when the logic and roundtrips to the database can be limited. For complicated queries, that maybe multipart and may require multiple separate sub-queries, a stored procedure is the way to go - both for performance (in the case of avoiding multiple round trips to the server) and debugging (run the T-SQL directly in SSMS until you have it exactly right).

99% of the time I do my queries in the code (linq/c#), but there are cases where stored procedures make sense and this maybe one of them for you.

Comment: and if there is a bug in the linq code then I have to recompile the whole thing and deploy it :(

Comment: ..so therefore automate your deployments and take that pain away

Comment: And of course you also have deployment procedures for your stored procedures...?

Comment: thank you, I think based on your answer I'll be able to make up my mind